# Why preventDefault does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, droppable

This is a part of my code.
If I try to drop an image on the block preventDefault does not work.

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
            $('#imgDropzone').on({
                dragenter: function(e) {
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#ffd1ff');
                },
                dragleave: function(e) {
                    $(this).css('background-color', '');
                },
                drop: function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    var el = $(this);
                    fileReader.onload = (function(file) {
                        return function(event) {
                            alert(event.target.result);
                        };
                    })(file);
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
            });
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LrmDw/

Comment: I wish SO had a built-in filter to detect questions that claim something "does not work" and then **fail to describe exactly what goes wrong.**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need<sup>*</sup> to prevent default for all the other drag events as well:

see http://jsfiddle.net/LrmDw/2/

```
$('#imgDropzone').on("dragenter dragstart dragend dragleave dragover drag drop", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

To explain what's not working in the original jsfiddle:

When you drop a file in the droparea (or anywhere in the page), the browser's default behavior is to navigate away and try to interpret the file. If you drop a normal
txt file for example, the browser will navigate away from jsfiddle and display contents of the txt file. This is in Chrome.

---

Btw, base64 urls are not preferable since they duplicate data. Simply grab a blob pointer to the file and use that:

```
var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
var src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
$("<img>", {src: src}).appendTo("body");
```

See

http://jsfiddle.net/LrmDw/3/

<sup>I don't know exactly which ones but I never had to care</sup>

Comment: Why is that?  What is the "default" behavior of "drop" anyway in a case like this?  That fiddle doesn't do anything interesting for me.

Comment: @Pointy to open the file in the browser and navigate away from the page. Drag a file to this page right now.. it will navigate away. In the jsfiddle, drop any file to the drop area.

Comment: Ah well OK I guess it does work for me then :-)  (I mean the "drop" works; the `preventDefault()` doesn't I guess.)

Comment: @Pointy the preventDefault is to prevent the browser opening the file so you can read its contents

Comment: Can you explain the asterisk behind "need" in your first sentence? Why would I care about preventing the default actions of other events, if I have prevented the default event of *dropping* the file? Sounds like a bug to me, because the browser only navigates to the contents of the file once it is *dropped* not while it is being dragged over the document.