# Backbone.js drop event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, drag-and-drop, marionette

I have problem with drop event.

In my template I have a `div` which is a drop area. When I drop a file I want disable reload site and show photo.

`prevenDefault()` doesn't work, my site is reloaded and I can see only photo which was uploaded

```
<div class="text-center js-upload">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
ui: {
   upload: '.js-upload'
},
events: {
  'drop @ui.upload': 'onDrop'
},
onDrop: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
},
```

Comment: Are you using a plugin for the file input? A file input won't submit by itself.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674349/why-preventdefault-does-not-work

Comment: You could either delete your question, write an answer and accept it, or mark your question as a duplicate of another question (if that's possible with your own question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used solution from 
[Why preventDefault does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674349/why-preventdefault-does-not-work)

```
$('#imgDropzone').on("dragenter dragstart dragend dragleave dragover drag drop", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In my example, I similarly added `preventDefault` for all [drag&drop events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#Drag_Events).